# How can I execute this function after finishing the upload function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm stuck in this code, I have a function that upload files to Google Drive. It works great! But I want to execute an aditional function after the upload of the file has been completed.
I tried with .then and new Promise but doesn't work

There is my code (function) :

```
var { google } = require("googleapis");
var drive = google.drive("v3");
var key = require("./private_key.json");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");

controller.uploadImage = (req, res) => {

var file_uploaded_to_drive = false;

var jwToken = new google.auth.JWT(
    key.client_email,
    null,
    key.private_key, ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
    null
);

jwToken.authorize((authErr) => {
    if (authErr) {
        console.log("error : " + authErr);
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("Authorization accorded");
    }
});

var file_name = 'Imagen No Subida....';

if (req.files) {
    var filePath = req.files.file.path;
    var fileSplit = filePath.split('\\');
    var fileName = fileSplit[2];
    var extSplit = fileName.split('\.');
    var fileExt = extSplit[1];

    if (fileExt == 'png' || fileExt == 'jpg' || fileExt == 'rar' || fileExt == 'mp3' || fileExt == 'mp4' || fileExt == 'wmv') {
        var folderId = "1HMTg8nv-FMf0N4BqNChF3LEW6EibK4FG";
        var fileMetadata = {
            'name': req.files.file.name,
            parents: [folderId]
        };
        var media = {
            mimeType: 'application/octet-stream',
            body: fs.createReadStream('../uploads/' + fileName)
        };
        drive.files.create({
            auth: jwToken,
            resource: fileMetadata,
            media: media,
            fields: 'id'
        }, function(err, file) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log('File Id: ', file.data.id);
                // ---- HERE THE FILE IS UPLOADED I THINK----
                return res.status(200).send({
                    files: req.files,
                    "codigo": file.data.id,
                });
                //AFTER THE UPLOAD I WANT TO EXECUTE SOMETHING LIKE THIS 
                // .then({
                //     console.log( 'Upload Complete')
                // });
            }
        });
    } else {
        fs.unlink(filePath, (err) => {
            return res.status(200).send({ message: 'La extensión no es valida' });
        });
    }
} else {
    return res.status(200).send({
        message: 'File doesn't uploaded'
    });
}
}
```

If I put the console in the bottom of the code, this is executed first and then the upload happens.
Some suggestion?

Comment: Calling `res.send()` finishes the request, so you need to call any other functions before sending the response back to the client app if they need to be part of the response. But are you sure you don't see 'Upload Complete' in the server logs? It won't be logged to the client obv, but should appear in your server logs if you have it enabled.

Comment: I'm not node.js expert but this looks like express.js code, and it seems that you send files you've just uploaded from browser back to the browser.

Comment: @Shilly uhm that `console.log` is just and example, i want to delete a file from a folder using `fs.unlink` but after upload for sure.